# How to add picklist (Field dependencies) for custom objects

Tags: custom-object, picklist, fields, dependent-picklist

I want to add picklist for a custom object I have created. When I navigate to Field dependencies for that custom object and click new the Controlling field and dependent field drop down list are empty.How can I populate them with other custom object created before  ?

Answer (score 3):

Dependent picklists can only work on the same object. That means that if a custom object A__c has a master-detail relationship with B__c, then a picklist on B__c can't reference the picklist from A__c.

Answer (score 1):

Standard and custom Checkboxes and Picklists can be CONTROLLING FIELDS. 
Custom Picklists and multi-select Picklists can be DEPENDENT FIELDS.

Hence if you have any of these type fields then only Controlling field and dependent field drop down list will be populated with selective options.

Answer (score 0):

If those objects are related you can also create set of validation rules that will define which values of picklist are allowed, but you cant hide other values.

The only way you can create such picklist is injecting some small VF page in layout.
In controller of this page you can define rules of setting values on this picklist.

Answer (score 0):

How to apply controlling picklist,dependent picklist for custom objects? 
please explain with simple example..